# как узнать высшую роль на сервере Discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

Мне надо, чтобы бот мог определить высшую роль пользователя и создать роль на одну выше, допустим чтобы выдать ему цвет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аттрибутом [top_role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.top_role)

```
@bot.command()
async def highest_role(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    member = ctx.author if not member else member
    await ctx.send(member.top_role)
```